# Google Scripts Server error on save

Tags: google-apps-script

I am just now starting to mess with Google Scripts. I wrote a super simple script that just opened a file and emailed it to myself. I couldn't save the script and got that "We're Sorry, there was a server error, please try again in a bit" error. I created a new file and didn't add a thing, and I still couldn't save it.

I thought maybe its because I was on an account that wasn't an @gmail.com so I switched to one that was. Still can't save a single thing.

Any thoughts on why this would be happening? Or is this a bigger problem than me?

Comment: " Or is this a bigger problem than me?" I'm afraid it is, same issue here, no script working...let's hope it will be short ;-)

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Seeing as I hadn't introduced any variables to the mix. Curses. I was really hoping this would be my solution. I hope that it isn't this always inconsistent.

Comment: Don't worry , I use gas for a couple of years and I could count on one hand the service failures... ( well a hand is even to much ;-)

Comment: It's always worth looking at: http://www.google.com/appsstatus. (Currently many yellow dots...)

Comment: Now it seems to be working again... at least on the scripts I tried.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a transient online service interruption, and is therefor relevant for only a short period of time.